# Scrolling issues in Android RecyclerView Android Galaxy-Tab

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement the RecyclerView in android. It successfully work on all the mobile devices except the tablet devices, that is unable to scroll the RecyclerView.Is any solution for solving this problem...?

Answer (score 0):

I have find out the error, that in my layout.xml file, i used both ScrollView and RecyclerView  in the same layout.Due to this the RecyclerView scrolling is disabled.So i removed the ScrollView from the xml its work fine.